# Backup hosting 3 Tb overall/10 Gb daily

Tags: backup, hosting

Could someone please advise a hosting for backing up data via FTP.
We need about 3 Tb overall space and acceptable speed to transfer about 10 Gb daily (incremental backup for photo hosting).

Hosting location could be Europe (preferred) or USA.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not married to the idea of using FTP, a managed backup service like [Backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com/index-k.html) (Win/Mac) or [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com) (Win/Mac/Linux) is almost certainly your least expensive option.

Comment: +1 for crashplan, its ruddy brilliant. Can seed the account with a  1TB USB drive they send out for a small fee to avoid the initial upload, and unlimited space for peanuts a month ($3 !)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)?

Or [jungledisk](https://www.jungledisk.com/business/) which uses rackspace or S3?

Comment: S3 seems to be too expensive for backup - it will take about 260 USD/month for 3 Tb.

Comment: Is it normal price for backups?

Comment: $260/mo is very reasonable for STORAGE, this isn't a backup solution though.

Comment: Amazon S3 is inaccessible via FTP :(

Comment: Yes, but there are many clients that offer similar functionality. What is the environment you're looking to back up?

Answer (score 0):

Logicworks if you want infiniBand interconnect and multi-tiered storage.